# Mobile phone fallback with custom basestation

Tags: wireless, mobile

If a custom base station was placed in an area with mobile devices nearby, would they automatically fall back to 2G from 3G, since the 2G signal was stronger? Or would the 3G signal need to be suppressed completely by a noise generator for a fallback to happen ?

The nearby target mobiles phones would be 70% Androids,20% iPhones and 10% 2G Only phones, this is Indian Mobile network specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the setting on the device. Per default the devices won't automatically fall back to 2G just because it is stronger. You will have to force them to by suppressing the 3G signal.

I don't know anything about Indian law, but I would suggest to check legality of this before implementing any mobile network jammer!

Comment: in my office i get 2 bars of my 3G network, if there is strong 2g network available the mobile will still work on 3g ?

Comment: The purpose is just to send an SMS and then disconnect

Comment: Yes, the most phones with default settings will stick to the 3G network because it is the superior network.